# Simple on edit trigger does not work - trying to get a notification whenever single cell reaches a certain value

Tags: google-apps-script, triggers

I have just started using Google App Scripts, I've seen many questions regarding triggers but all seemed very advanced to me.

I have a simple script to send me an email whenever this single cell value exceeds a threshold, in this case 250. The cell is B252 and it has a formula in it (sum of B2 to B251).

```
function sendEmail() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("FormResponses");
  var value = sheet.getRange("B252").getValue();

    if (value >= 250) {
      var emailAddress = "my_email_address";
      var subject = "test";
      var message = "test"
      
      MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
      sheet.getRange("B253").setValue("NOTIFICATION SENT");
  }
}
```

The code works fine when I run it through editor or through the menu. I set up a trigger selecting event type "on edit". Then I tried editing anything in the table, but the trigger seem to not work. In the execution history, I don't see any Trigger type execution. What am I missing here?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this and make it an installable trigger:

```
function sendEmail(e) {
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  if(sh.getName() == "FormResponses" && sh.getRange("B252").getValue() > 249) {
      var emailAddress = "my_email_address";
      var subject = "test";
      var message = "test"
      MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
      sh.getRange("B253").setValue("NOTIFICATION SENT");
  }
}
```

Do not attempt to run this function without supplying the event object into the argument e.  Personally I would run this from an onFormSubmit trigger.  I don't understand why you wound not do this for every submission.  I'd like to see and image of the sheet.